# MudBlazor - Is there any way to select text within Dialog?

Tags: mudblazor

When I try to select text inside a Dialog (example in yellow in the image below), the text is not selected. To stay selected, it is necessary to place the mouse cursor next to the "F" of "first" and pull everything down. The objective is to be able to select with the mouse cursor, text that is in the middle of the Dialog.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css property:

user-select: all;

to "Dialog Content" paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with next release:

https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/5355